# Sourcetree asks to download binary content for git lfs on every startup

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

Face the same problem when I open Sourcetree.
My Sourcetree version is 3.4.9.

[image]

does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: What makes you think there's something wrong here? You're using Git-LFS (not just Git: Git-LFS is a sort of wrapper software, that enfolds Git into an outer layer in which LFS plays games *with* Git so that Git thinks it's doing one thing but LFS is doing another) and your Sourcetree display shows that Git-LFS is now engaged in its thing.

Comment: it can not stop and continue for a long time. Moreover, it do not download any git-lfs file.
So I think it is a bug.

Comment: It could be a bug, but at this point it's probably either an Atlassian-only bug, or a Git-LFS bug, rather than anything to do with Git. The way to find out is to watch what's going on at a lower level (e.g., is there any network traffic happening and if so what is it).